# How to make Striped RML table in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo, rml

I am going to implement `BlockTable`, I have taken a `BlockTable` inside 
section and I want `<tr>` color dynamic, like striped(one white & one grey)
but have no idea how to do.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

that's a little bit tricky thing, you should refer to "survey" module's report of openerp, which has such reports. I hope it helps.

Cheers,
Parthiv